# First Activity gets closed in background from Second activity

Tags: android

I am facing one issue and its a bit weird.
My case is,
I have two Activity A and B.
A is my launcher activity so when i open app A is presented.
Now from button click i start another activity B.

Now i am placing my app in background by pressing home button of the phone.
and coming again in the app from recent.
Now i am in activity B when my app comes to foreground.

Now when i press back button my application is closing instead of going back to Activity A.

Why is this happening can anyone please explain and also how can i solve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:noHistory="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Could you paste your manifest file and activity code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Activity in background gets killed when Home button is pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100905/activity-in-background-gets-killed-when-home-button-is-pressed)

Comment: check weather you are destroying the activity A or using flag on button click.

Comment: @Mr.vdtarsariya : Do you have an answer to the above question?

Comment: @Habeeb : No i do not

Comment: @Mr.vdtarsariya I would say to please take that language elsewhere, but there really is no place for that kind of language at all

Comment: @HardikChauhan please post your code with manifest

Comment: Please provide some relevant code so we can have a look, especially the part where you launch the second activity, and possibly what you have in the onDestroy of A and onResume of B

Comment: @HardikChauhan You better pasot your code. Without viewing your code we cant respond.

Comment: Sure will post a code

Comment: In activity its just a simple code for calling another activity by intent.

Answer (score 3):

Remove `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` from

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:launchMode="singleInstance"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:noHistory="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```